# Can't figure out how to properly style DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm kinda new to Flutter and I'm building an app for a college project, but I'm having problems with this widget.

[DropdownButton input value in white color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWRNz.png)

[DropdownButton input value in black color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6YTA.png)

This is my DropdownButton code, it appears with the Hint in white color, but when I select an item the value in the button appears as black. If I change the DropdownButton color to white, then when the popup appears the background-color is white and so the font-color. This way I can't see the items, because they're the same color as the background.

```
class DropdownWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final IconData arrowIcon;
  final String hint;
  final List items;
  final Stream stream;
  final Function onChanged;

  DropdownWidget({this.icon, this.arrowIcon, this.hint, this.items, this.stream, this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("Snapshot data -> ${snapshot.data}");
        return InputDecorator(
          child: DropdownButton(
            icon: Icon( arrowIcon, color: Colors.white,),
            hint: Text( hint, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            items: items.map((value) {
              print("Valor do item $value");
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value.runtimeType == int ? value.toString() : value, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: onChanged,
            value: snapshot.data,
            isExpanded: true,
            style: TextStyle(
//              color: Colors.black,
              color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
            underline: Container(),
            isDense: true,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: icon == null ? null : Icon(icon, color: Colors.white,),
            hintText: hint,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 5,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 24,
              top: 30
            ),
            errorText: snapshot.hasError ? snapshot.error : null,
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

What could I do to solve this? Is there a way to make the popup's background-color darker or just the value inside the button in a different color from the item's color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your DropDownButton in a Theme. Example code:

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.black), //this is where the magic happens
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropDownValue,
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropDownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
```

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark it as the answer for other people who might be wondering about the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

**For those, who have also smashed against the brutal reality finding a way to add a dropdown with Flutter.**

As mentioned by @asterisk12 adding `canvasColor` to the Theme is the way to change the background for the dropdown list.

**My answer is for the rest of you still battling with OTHER styling issues**
I am leaving here an example of how I managed to achieve (almost) what I needed:

- list appears below the button
- button is rectangular
- there is a hint text
- list is the same width as button

[image]
[image]

**For it to work you will need a `dropdown_button2` dependency (https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2/install)**

```
class DropDownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> options;

  const DropDownButton({Key? key, required this.options}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDownButton> createState() => _DropDownButtonState();
}

class _DropDownButtonState extends State<DropDownButton> {
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 5, 2, 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton2<String>(
              dropdownElevation: 0,
              hint: const Text(
                'Select Item',
              ),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_downward,
              ),
              iconSize: 30,
              isExpanded: true,
              iconEnabledColor: Colors.teal,
              buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
              value: selectedValue,
              dropdownMaxHeight: 150,
              scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,

              items: widget.options
                  .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e)))
                  .toList(),
              offset: const Offset(0, 3),

              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value;
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Details:**

- remove the shadow from the list: `dropdownElevation: 0`
- add a custom icon to `DropdownButton2`:

```
 icon: const Icon(
     Icons.arrow_downward,),
 iconSize: 30,
```

- Making the list scrollbar(you see it only when all elements do not fit in the dropdown, you can make `dropdownMaxHeight` smaller to see the difference).

```
scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
```

- Last but not least change the position of the list:

you can go wild :D and make some weird position
`offset: const Offset(-20, -3),`
[image]

or you can go not that wild and keep it as in my example so, that there is no space between button and the list
`offset: const Offset(0, 3),`

[image]

Hope I could help someone as desperate as I have recently been and save a bit of time for you.